# How do I implement a custom bottomnavigation like this

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

I need to implement a custom bottomnavigation like in the image. My peculiar issue is that when a menu item from the bottomNav is clicked the bottomnav has to reposition the text above and add an image of a dot below it like as shown in the image.

This means that small solutions to selected state like using a custom selector cannot solve this.

Is there a way to inflate a selected layout to show how the bottomNav should look when selected? What methods or other ways do you suggest I tackle this issue?

[image]

Comment: Check this out : [BubbleTabBar](https://github.com/akshay2211/BubbleTabBar?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=7841)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! Totally forgot to answer this after I solved it.

I was initially showing an **Icon and label combination** in the bottomnavigation. I was looking for a way to hide the icon on click and show a dot on the bottom which was the wrong way to go and would be complex.

I ended up adding the icon and label as a `group drawable vector` instead of  individually. So for each bottomnavigation option, I had a `drawable selector xml` with state for selected and unselected.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Git library It's not 100% same as want, but good

https://github.com/iammert/ReadableBottomBar